# What is the difference between additionalItems and additionalProperties in JSON Schema?

Tags: javascript, json, schema, jsonschema

In [JSON Schema](http://json-schema.org), what is the difference between `additionalProperties` and `additionalItems`, as I see examples of both used to specify whether a document containing elements not defined in the schema should be considered valid.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As of 2019-09 json-schema specification version, [additionalProperties](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#additionalProperties) is a validation keyword for objects/documents, and [additionalItems](https://json-schema.org/draft/2019-09/json-schema-core.html#additionalItems) is a validation keyword for arrays.

Comment: the only reference for additionalItems  in your link refers to meta information moving it to some other repo.